# In-cabinet power outlets flush with wall or cabinet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, cabinets

I have a couple of power outlets in my cabinets, one for a built-in microwave, the other for a countertop light. Should they be **(1) flush with  the wall** and have the opening in the cabinet cut out bigger so that a face plate can be installed resting on the wall or **(2) flush with the cabinet**, using an electrical box extension, so that the face plate rests on the cabinet?

The advantage of (1) is that it spares using box extensions but of (2) it preserves more of the structurally important horizontal boards in the back of the cabinet on the top and bottom but the advantage and it also looks more elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ruling factor is that the junction box must be made of an appropriate material.  *Not particle board*.

If you have a junction box inset into the wall so it's flush, and then you put 3/4" of wood material above it, and use the long outlet screws to mount *through* that, then effectively the junction box walls are wood.  So if things get sparking or molten-copper-dripping in there, it sets the wood on fire. Whee!

You may say "but they allow this with drywall!"  Drywall doesn't burn.  It's used as a firestop, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the proposed options involves any particle board.  The junction box is either installed in the wall as usual, and a cover plate installed as normal, or a box extension is installed.  Or in a different situation, the box could have been installed to protrude through the cabinet.

Not sure where OP is, but I believe any of those would meet code (subject to any rules about outlets being powered off when cabinet doors are closed), so it's personal preference.  I'd probably extend and mount flush to the cabinet if it was a thick cabinet wall, and cut a hole through to the wall for a thin cabinet wall.

Comment: Could you expand on the "rules about outlets being powered off when cabinet doors are closed"? Are you implying that the outlet for an under cabinet mount microwave must automatically lose power if the cabinet in which the outlet is mounted is closed? i.e. I have to have the cabinet door above the microwave open in order to use it? If that's what you're saying, then I'd like to see a code source for that one and the mechanism used to automatically cut power to an outlet when a door is closed.

Comment: Sure, in my jurisdiction (Ontario, Canada, and I suspect others as well) you can only have an outlet inside a cabinet (e.g. an appliance garage or a bathroom vanity) if the outlet is powered off when the door is closed.  Something about not leaving a hot curling iron on in an enclosed space.  An under-cabinet mounted anything wouldn't typically be plugged in to such an outlet.  The OP called his a "built-in microwave" which I would expect to either be hard-wired or plugged in to a dedicated circuit that wasn't switched.  I just mentioned it because it seemed relevant in a general sense.

Comment: As for the mechanism, a contact switch:
https://www.google.com/search?q=door+contact+switch+120v